# When the chart is rotated by 90 it does not appear

Tags: color, amsmath, tcolorbox

I have a problem when the chart is rotated by 90 degrees it doesn't show up

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{walidex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}     %المخطط 
\tikzset{a/.style={rectangle,align=center,inner sep=0.5mm ,text width= 5 cm,centered,fill=blue!7}}
\tikzset{b/.style={rectangle,inner sep=0.5mm ,align=center,text width= 6.5 cm,centered,fill=a5dar!30}}
\tikzset{loop/.style={ % requires library shapes.misc
        fill=yellow!7,
        chamfered rectangle,
        chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm
    },}
\tikzset{r/.style={rounded corners=2mm}}
\definecolor{coulFond}{rgb}{0.00, 0.48, 0.65}
\definecolor{vioolet}{RGB}{120,28,104}
\tikzset{AA/.style={draw,font=\tt\large,double,rectangle,midway ,chamfered rectangle,color=vioolet,chamfered rectangle corners={north east, south west},text width=7cm,text centered,inner sep=0pt,align=center,text width= 5 cm,centered,text=vioolet}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style} 
 \DeactivateBG
 \dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\newpage 

\ActivateBG 
 
\chapter{التحليل التوافقي}
\hypertarget{sec:0}{}
%\startcontents[chapters]
\printmyminitoc

%%%
\section{مقدّمة}
\section{المبدأ الأساسي للعد}
%\lipsum[1-16]
 

 
\chapter{الجبر الخطي}
\hypertarget{sec:1}{}
%\startcontents[chapters]
\printmyminitoc

\textcolor{blue}{\large\samar
مخطط ذهني لإزالة حالات عدم التعيين  : }

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[edge from parent/.style={},sibling distance=10cm]
\node[chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={north east, south west},double,draw,text width=5cm,text centered,fill=red!5,font=\sf,chamfered rectangle ysep=0pt](a) {\RL{حالة عدم التعيين $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$}}
%
child {node[fill=blue!10](c) {\RL{$f(x)$
تتضمن كثيرات حدود فقط}}
child[level distance=3cm] {
{node[fill=green!10,text width=8cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt](e) {
\RL{
تطبيق القاعدة التالية :\\
\textcolor{red}{\sf عند اللانهاية :}
كثير الحدود له نفس نهاية الحد الأكبر درجة.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \pm\infty}
a_n x^n+\ldots+a_1 x+a_0=\lim\limits_{x\to \pm\infty}a_n x^n
 $$
}
}
}}}
child {node[fill=blue!10](b) {\RL{$f(x)$
تتضمن جذرًا
\,
$\sqrt{•\quad}$
}}
child[level distance=3.5cm] {node[fill=green!10,text width=6cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt](d) {
\RL{
نستعمل طريقة التحليل :\\
وضع الحد الأكبر درجة كعامل مشترك .
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}&=|x|\sqrt{a+\dfrac{b}{x}+\dfrac{c}{x^2}}\\
\sqrt{\alpha x +\beta}&=|x|\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha}{x}+\dfrac{\beta}{x^2}}
\end{align*}
}}}
}
;
% arraws 
\begin{scope}[->,rounded corners,line width=1pt,purple]
\draw (a.south)|-(b.west);
\draw (a.south)|-(c.east);
\draw (b.south)|-(d.north);
\draw (c.south)|-(e.north);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%----2--------------
\begin{center}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,align=center] 
\node   [chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={north east, south west},double,draw,text width=5cm,text centered,fill=red!5,font=\sf,chamfered rectangle ysep=0pt](A){\RL{حالة عدم التعيين $+\infty-\infty$}};
\node   [fill=blue!10,rectangle,below=0.3cm of A](B)
{\RL{$f(x)$
تتضمن جذرًا
\,
$\sqrt{•\quad}$
}};
%
\node   [fill=green!10,   below right= 2cm and 2.5cm of A](C){
$f(x)=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}+\alpha x+\beta$
};
\node   [fill=green!10,below= 0.5cm of B](D){
$f(x)=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-\sqrt{\alpha x^2+\beta x + \gamma}$};
\node   [fill=green!10, below left=3cm of A ](E){
$f(x)=\sqrt{ax+b}+\alpha x+\beta$};
\node[diamond,fill= yellow!50,below=0.2cm of C.south east,font=\small,,inner sep=1pt](F){$\sqrt{a}\neq |\alpha|$};
\node[diamond,fill= yellow!50,below=0.2cm of C.south west,font=\small,,inner sep=1pt](G){$\sqrt{a}=|\alpha|$};
%
\node[diamond,fill= gray!20,below=0.5cm of D.south east,font=\small,inner sep=1pt](I){${a}= {\alpha}$};
\node[diamond,fill= gray!20,below=0.5cm of D.south west,font=\small,,inner sep=2pt](J){${a}\neq {\alpha}$};
%
\node   [xshift=-1cm,fill=blue!10,rectangle,below  =1cm of G,font=\tt\large](K)
{\RL{ 
نستعمـــــل طريقـــة المرافــــق
}};
\node   [text width=10cm,fill=blue!10,below=6cm of B,font=\tt\Large](L)
{\RL{ 
نضـــــع
$x$
كـعامـــــل مشتــــرك
}};

% arraws 
\begin{scope}[->,rounded corners,line width=1pt,purple]
\draw (A.south)--(B.north);
\draw (B.east)-|(C.north);
\draw (B.south)--(D.north);
\draw (B.west)-|(E.north);
\draw (C.south)|-(F.west);
\draw (C.south)|-(G.east);
\draw (D.south)|-(I.west);
\draw (D.south)|-(J.east);
%
\draw (I.south)--($(K.north)-(1cm,0)$);
\draw (G.south)--($(K.north)+(1cm,0)$);
%
\draw (F.south)|-(L.east);
\draw (E.south)|-(L.west);
\draw (J.south)--($(L.north west)+(1.9cm,0)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}
\end{center}
%----3------------
%\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[edge from parent/.style={},sibling distance=5.2cm]
\node[chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle corners={north east, south west},double,draw,text width=5cm,text centered,fill=red!5,font=\sf,chamfered rectangle ysep=0pt](a) {\RL{حالة عدم التعيين $\dfrac{0}{0}$}}
%4
child {node[fill=blue!10](e) {\RL{$f(x)$
تتضمن 
$\sin x$
و
$\cos x$
}}
child[level distance=3cm] {
{node[fill=green!10,text width=3.3cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt](i) {
\RL{
 نظهر إحدى النهايات الشهيرة التالية :
\begin{flushleft}
 $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$\\
$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos x}{x}=0$
\end{flushleft}
}
}
}}}
%3
child {node[fill=blue!10](d) {\RL{
المقام من الشكل
\textcolor{red}{$(\alpha x+ \beta)$}
}}
child[level distance=3.5cm] {node[fill=green!10,text width=5.1cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt](h) {
\RL{
نستعمل طريقة العدد المشتق :
\begin{enumerate}
\item
إظهار العبارة :
$\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$
\\
$\dfrac{........}{\alpha x+ \beta}=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\times \dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$
\item 
$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=g'(a)$
\end{enumerate}
}}}
}
%2
child {node[fill=blue!10](c) {\RL{
$f(x)$
تتضمن جذرًا
\,
$\sqrt{•\quad}$
}}
child[level distance=3cm] {node[fill=green!10,text width=4cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt] (g){
\RL{
نستعمل طريقة المرافق :
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
نضرب :
$f(x)
\times
\dfrac{\text{\textcolor{red}{المرافق}}}{\text {\textcolor{red}{المرافق}}}
$
\item 
ثم نختزل على :
\textcolor{red}{$(x-a)$}
\end{enumerate}
}}}
}
%1
child {node[fill=blue!10](b) {\RL{
$f(x)$
تتضمن كثيرات حدود
}}
child[level distance=3.2cm] {node[fill=green!10,text width=3.8cm,align=flush right,chamfered rectangle,chamfered rectangle ysep=10pt](f) {
\RL{
 نستعمل طريقة الإختزال :
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item 
 نحلّل البسط والمقام.
 \item 
 ثم نختزل على 
\textcolor{red}{$(x-a)$}
 \end{enumerate}
 $f(x)=\dfrac{\cancel{\textcolor{red}{(x-a)}}(\cdots\cdots)}{\cancel{\textcolor{red}{(x-a)}}(\cdots\cdots)
}$}}
}}
;
% arraws 
\begin{scope}[->,rounded corners,line width=1pt,purple]
\draw (a.east)-|(b.north);
\draw (a.south)|-(c.west);
\draw (a.south)|-(d.east);
\draw (a.west)-|(e.north);
\draw (b.south)--(f.north);
\draw (c.south)--(g.north);
\draw (d.south)--(h.north);
\draw (e.south)--(i.north);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}
\end{center}




\section{عنوان أول}
 ,,,
\newpage
dd
%%
\chapter{مسلّمات الاحتمالات}
 \hypertarget{sec:2}{}
\printmyminitoc
\section{مقدّمة}
\section{فراغ العينة و الحوادث} 
\newpage
dd
\chapter{معًا من أجل تعلم  }
 \hypertarget{sec:3}{}
 \printmyminitoc
\section{عنوان أول}
,
\newpage
dd
\end{document}
```

the walidex document

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{walidex}[24/05/2020 v1]

% La classe manEN2019.cls s'appuie sur la structure de la classe book
% pour le sectionnage (chapter, section ...)
 
\LoadClassWithOptions{report}
%\RequirePackage{mathpazo} % Police d'écriture

\RequirePackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,
    %showframe,
    top=128pt,
    height=620pt,
    headheight=20pt,
   % headsep=80pt
  ]{geometry}
%
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,atbegshi,lastpage}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{adforn} %decoration gliphs
\RequirePackage[pageanchor=true
,pdfstartview=FitH,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=red ,bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{bookmark}
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\bookmarksetup{color=red,bold,
}
%\bookmark[named=FirstPage,color=red]{صفحة الغلاف}
\bookmark[named=FirstPage,color=blue]{قائمة المحتويات}
%
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
%\RequirePackage{alphalph}
%\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{totcount}
\RequirePackage[contents={}]{background}
%\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{tikz,fancyhdr,titletoc}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[arabic]{minitoc}
\RequirePackage{framed}
%\RequirePackage[compact,pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % 
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,positioning}
\definecolor{secnum}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{ptcbackground}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{ptctitle}{RGB}{0,177,235}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\color{ptctitle}\contentsname}{}{}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{13,151,225}
\definecolor{headcolor2}{RGB}{212,237,252}
\definecolor{headcolor}{RGB}{0,177,235}
\definecolor{KLEIN}{HTML}{002fa7}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{ff0000}
%%%
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=algeria]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Aref Ruqaa}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Aljazeera}
%%
\newcount\segmentsleft
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
circle fraction/.style args={#1/#2}{code={%
\segmentsleft=#1\relax
\pgfmathloop
\ifnum\segmentsleft<1\else
\ifnum\segmentsleft<#2 \edef\n{\the\segmentsleft}\else\def\n{#2}\fi
\begin{scope}[shift={(\pgfmathcounter,0)}]
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1)+90;}] in {1,...,\n}
\fill[fill=\mycolor] (0,0) -- (\a:0.8) arc (\a:\a+360/#2:0.8) -- cycle;
%\draw[white] circle [radius=1.5];
\draw[\mycolor] circle [radius=0.8];
\ifnum#2>1
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1);}] in {1,...,#2}
\draw[white] (0,0) -- (90+\a:0.8);
\node[circle,draw=\mycolor,fill=white,minimum width=0.5cm,align=center] at (0,0){\ttfamily \thepage
};
\fi
%
\end{scope}
\advance\segmentsleft by-#2
\repeatpgfmathloop
}}
}
%%%
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, withShadow/.style={
      blur shadow={
        shadow blur steps=10,
        shadow blur extra rounding=2pt, 
        shadow xshift=1pt,
        shadow yshift=-2pt
      }
    }]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytotalchapters}{\totvalue{chapter} > 0 ? \totvalue{chapter} : 20}
            \ifcase\thechapter
                \xdef\mycolor{ptcbackground}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{red}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{ao}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \else \xdef\mycolor{black}
            \fi
 {
        \fill[\mycolor,withShadow,] ($(current page.north west)+(0,0)$)        ..
        controls+(-68:3.2)and+(120:4.25)..
      % ($(current page.north west)+(4,-3)$)--
          ($(current page.north east)+(-6,-3)$)
 arc(180:42:1.5)         
         --
($(current page.north east)+(-2,-2)$)arc(180:0:0.5)
--
($(current page.north east)+(-1,-4)$) ..
controls+(270:1)and+(120:0)..
($(current page.north east)+(0,-5)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(0,0)$)  
--cycle;
\fill[\mycolor,path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 20 percent]  ($(current page.north east)+(-4.5,-3)$) circle(1.2cm)  
        node[align=center,xshift=0.4cm] (c1)
              {\fontsize{70}{70} \selectfont 
\color{white}
$\chapterlabel$ 
              };
\fill[\mycolor!10,withShadow, ]
($(current page.north east)+(-3.2,-2.1)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(-1.9,-2.1)$)arc(180:0:0.4)--
($(current page.north east)+(-1.1,-3)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(-3.2,-3)$)--cycle             
 node [font=\Large,xshift=+1cm,yshift=-0.4 cm]{\ttfamily \color{\mycolor} المحور};
 %
\draw[\mycolor,line width=0.3cm]($(current page.south west)+(0,0.8)$)--($(current page.south)+(-3,0.8)$) 
node[right,font=\small]{\RL{ \color{black} #1  }};
\draw[\mycolor,line width=0.1cm]($(current page.south west)+(0,0.5)$)--($(current page.south)+(-3,0.5)$);
%rosseur
%\clip ($(A)+(-.1\textwidth,0)$) rectangle ($(B)+(\textwidth,0)$);
%$(B)+(.66\textwidth,0)$:
\begin{scope} 
\fill[\mycolor ,rounded corners=5pt,withShadow,] ($(current page.north west)+
(+3,-1.4cm)$)rectangle
($(current page.north)+
(1,-3.4cm)$);
\foreach \y in {.01,.05,...,.4}{
\fill[draw=black,fill=gray!10] ($(current page.north)+
(-\y\textwidth,-1.6cm)$) circle (1mm) ($(current page.north)+(-\y\textwidth,-0.9cm)$) circle (1mm) ;
\draw[line width=0.5mm,\mycolor,double=yellow, line cap=round]($(current page.north)+
(-\y\textwidth,-1.6cm)$) arc (270:90:{1.6mm} and {3.5mm});
}
\end{scope}
\node[align=center] at ($(current page.north)+(-3.5,-2.4)$)
{\RL{\sffamily \color{white} #1  }};}
%
\fill[\mycolor,withShadow,] 
 ($(current page.south east)+(-2,1)$)arc(180:90:1)--
($(current page.south east)+(-1,1.8)$)--
%
($(current page.south east)+(-1,4)$)..
controls+(90:1)and+(210:0)..
($(current page.south east)+(0,5)$)
%
--
($(current page.south east)+(0,0.9)$)
arc(0:220:0.8cm)--($(current page.south)+(5,0.4)$)
..controls+(90:0.7)and+(210:0)..
($(current page.south)+(6,+1)$)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}  
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{0pt}
%%%%%toc section
%%%%%toc section
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%hypperlink
\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let             \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
                \p3 = (sourcenode.south west),
                \n1={\x2-\x1},
                \n2={\y1-\y2},
                \n3={atan2(\y2-\y3,\x2-\x3)},
                \n4={veclen(\y2-\y3,\x2-\x3)},
                \n5={veclen(\y1-\y3,\x1-\x3)}
                 in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,anchor=south
            west,at=(\p3),rotate=\n3]
            {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n4}{\n5}}}}}
                    %xelatex needs \XeTeXLinkBox, won't create a link unless it
                    %finds text --- rules don't work without \XeTeXLinkBox.
                    %Still builds correctly with pdflatex and lualatex
        }
    }
}
% to have access to the total number of chapters
  
\regtotcounter{chapter}
%%
%
% every chapter starts on a new page
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{}{}

% auxiliary lengths for the height of the frame and the width of each tab
\newlength\mylen
\newlength\mylena
%
%
% style for the chapter tabs
\tikzset{
tab/.style={
  text width=\mylena,
  thick,
  rectangle,
  rounded corners=0pt,
  align=center,
  text width=53pt,
  inner sep=-5pt,
  fill=\mycolor!10,
  font=\ttfamily\LARGE, 
  }
}
% style for the current chapter tab
\tikzset{selectedtab/.style={tab, rectangle, ,text width=68pt, rounded corners=8pt,color=white,inner sep=-3pt,fill=\mycolor,font=\ttfamily\LARGE}}
% the page number is showed in the background material
%\pagestyle{empty}

\AtBeginDocument{
% calculation of the width for each tab
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm\relax}
\ifnum\totvalue{chapter}>0
\setlength\mylena{\dimexpr\mylen/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
\fi

% the main part; as background material we place the border, 
% the chapter (current and other) tabs and the page number 
\newcommand\DeactivateBG{\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}
\newcommand\ActivateBG{
\backgroundsetup{
%position=current page.north west,
scale=0.8,
color=black,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents= {
%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytotalchapters}{\totvalue{chapter} > 0 ? \totvalue{chapter} : 20}
            \ifcase\thechapter
                   \xdef\mycolor{ptcbackground}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{red}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{ao}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \else \xdef\mycolor{black}
            \fi
 { \node[
    inner sep=0pt,
    text width=\the\dimexpr\textwidth+2.7cm\relax
  ] 
    at (current page.north west) (border) {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-6cm\relax}};}{
  \foreach \valchapter in {0,...,\numexpr\totvalue{chapter}-1\relax}
  {
    \node[hyperlink node=sec:\valchapter,
      \ifnum\thechapter<\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
        tab%
      \else 
      \ifnum\thechapter>\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax 
        tab%
      \else 
      selectedtab%
      \fi\fi,
      minimum height=\mylena
      ] 
      at ([yshift=-(.5+\valchapter)*\mylena]border.north west) 
      (tab-\valchapter) 
      {\hspace*{0pt}\rotatebox{+90}{%
        {\textarabic{\ttfamily\chaptername \the\numexpr\valchapter+1\relax}}%
        }
      };
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}}
  }
}
  }
%
%
%
\cfoot{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}

 \fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,withShadow/.style={
      blur shadow={
        shadow blur steps=10,
        shadow blur extra rounding=2pt, 
        shadow xshift=1pt,
        shadow yshift=-2pt
      }}]
\fill[ \mycolor!10,withShadow,line width=2pt]
 ($(current page.north east)+(-1.5,-0.5)$) rectangle
 ($(current page.south east)+(0,1.8)$); 
  %
%
\fill[draw= \mycolor,fill=\mycolor!10,line width=2pt,,withShadow]
($(current page.north)+(0,0)$)-- 
($(current page.north)+(-1,-0.6)$)--
($(current page.north)+(0,-1.2)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(2,-1.2)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(1,0)$)--cycle
; 
\fill[draw= gray,fill=\mycolor]
($(current page.north)+(0,-0.2)$)-- 
($(current page.north)+(-0.8,-0.6)$)--
($(current page.north)+(0,-1)$)--cycle;
%()
\fill[\mycolor,withShadow] 
($(current page.north east)+(-2.2,0)$)
[rounded corners=6pt]
--
($(current page.north east)+(-2.2,-1)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(-1,-1)$)
[rounded corners=0pt]--
($(current page.north east)+(-1,-4)$) ..
controls+(270:1)and+(120:0)..
($(current page.north east)+(0,-5)$)--
($(current page.north east)+(0,0)$)  
--cycle;    
   %
   \fill[\mycolor,withShadow,] 
 ($(current page.south east)+(-2,1)$)arc(180:90:1)--
($(current page.south east)+(-1,1.8)$)--
%
($(current page.south east)+(-1,4)$)..
controls+(90:1)and+(210:0)..
($(current page.south east)+(0,5)$)
%
--
($(current page.south east)+(0,0.9)$)
arc(0:220:0.8cm)--($(current page.south)+(5,0.4)$)
..controls+(90:0.7)and+(210:0)..
($(current page.south)+(6,+1)$)--cycle;
\node(ab) at ($(current page.north east)+(-5,-0.6)$){\large{\RL{\ttfamily \color{\mycolor}  \rightmark }}};
\node[rotate=90,draw=\mycolor, rectangle,rounded corners=5pt,fill=\mycolor,inner sep=02pt] at ($(current page.east)+(-0.7,0)$){\LARGE{\RL{\ttfamily \color{white} \leftmark }}};
%
\draw[\mycolor,line width=0.3cm]($(current page.south west)+(0,0.8)$)--($(current page.south)+(-3,0.8)$) ;
\draw[\mycolor,line width=0.1cm]($(current page.south west)+(0,0.5)$)--($(current page.south)+(-3,0.5)$);
%
 %
%rosseur
%rosseur
\end{tikzpicture}
   }
\fancyfoot[R]{\scalebox{0.9}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=+0.485cm,yshift=+0.92cm,overlay]
  \ifnum \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}>0
%
  \begin{scope}%[shift={(2cm,0) },overlay]
\foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y]
in {\value{page}/\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}{
\pic at (0, -\y) {circle fraction={\numerator/\denominator}};
}
\end{scope}
 \else \relax \fi 
 %  
  \end{tikzpicture} }
  %
%
}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}% Custom footer
  % Line at the footer visible
%}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
 %%
%
 \addto\captionsarabic{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{ المحور}%
   \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{\ttfamily{ عناويـن المحور :}}
 % \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\leter f}% 
}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%
%%%
%%%%%%%minitoc
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
%\mtcsetoffset{minitoc}{-4.0em}  % To shift the minitoc to the left, if needed!
\setlength{\mtcindent}{+2em}
  \newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \vskip-0.9cm
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}
    \noindent\hspace{-0.5cm}%
    %\colorlet{secnumbercolor}{white}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=\mycolor!10,align=left, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},inner sep=2mm](min){%
        \color{\mycolor}%      
        \begin{minipage}{12cm}%minipage trick
     \begin{RTL}
       {\minitoc}
        \end{RTL}
        \end{minipage}};
        \draw[rounded corners,line width=6pt,\mycolor](min.north east)--(min.north west)--([yshift=-0.5cm]min.north west);
                \draw[rounded corners,line width=6pt,\mycolor]([yshift=0.5cm]min.south east)--
                (min.south east)
                --(min.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}} %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%section
\newcommand\SecTitle[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (numsec) {\bf\thesection};
\fill[rounded corners=2pt,fill=gray] ($(numsec.north west)+(2pt,-2pt)$) -- ($(numsec.north east)+(1mm,0mm)+(2pt,-2pt)$) -- ($(numsec.south east)+(2pt,-2pt)$) -- ($(numsec.south west)+(-1mm,0)+(2pt,-2pt)$) -- cycle;
\fill[rounded corners=2pt,fill=\mycolor] (numsec.north west) -- ($(numsec.north east)+(1mm,0mm)$) -- (numsec.south east) -- ($(numsec.south west)+(-1mm,0)$) -- cycle;
\node[white] at (numsec) {\bf\thesection};
\node[\mycolor,left  =0.5cm of numsec] {\RL{\Large\sffamily#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\SecTitle{#1}}
%%%
% Fixing the appearance of the footer in the empty pages in between chapters.
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}
% Finished fixing appearance

\titlecontents{section}
  [4em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-3em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax}{1pt}}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [5.8em]{\sffamily}
  {\color{secnum}\contentslabel{2.3em}\normalcolor}{}
  {\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage\\\hspace*{-5.8em}\vspace*{2pt}%
    \color{white}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt\relax}{1pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth>\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \colorbox{ptctitle}{\strut%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7pt\relax][l]{%
          \color{white}\bfseries\sffamily#1%
          \nobreak\hfill\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}}\par\smallskip
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand\PartialToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=ptcbackground,hidealllines=true]
\printcontents[chapters]{l}{1}{\colorbox{ptctitle}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \strut\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\makebox[5em]{%
      Chapter~\thechapter\hfill}Contents}}\vskip5pt}
\end{mdframed}%
}
```

Comment: Welcome. // A suggestion: Certainly most people won't know or have access to the walidex documentclass. In consequence we hardly can help, with few exceptions. So ... do you still have this problem when you use a standard class like article AND removed incompatible commands? If so, please post that modified code, too. (via EDIT) Thank you

Comment: Notice that we were able to edit your post so that the code was properly formatted.  You can do this by highlighting your code and clicking `{}`.  Thank you for providing the walidex document.  But do you have this problem without the walidex document?  You've posted a lot of code for us to look at, and most of it is unrelated to the problem at hand.  It will help everyone if you take the time to remove the unrelated code.

Comment: Do you have to use that class? Because, if not, I wouldn't.